# How to determine TCP/IP message types

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Rather new to socket programming in general.  I am developing a C# application and basically I want the client to send files and text.  How would the server be able to interpret the difference between the two?  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?  Do I just prepend some kind of textual descriptor?  So the first few bytes describes what the netstream is about?

Any advice or even resources that I should look into would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing built into TCP to do this, it just transmits bytes. You have to design an application protocol that specifies how to interpret the data. The details are entirely up to you.

Comment: Exactly...**YOU** have to decide upon some type of protocol that allows you to differentiate what kind of data is coming over the line.  That can be done with "headers" that let the receiver know what kind of data, and how much, to expect.  Delimiters can also be used, as well as a combination of the two.

Comment: There are plenty of existing protocol that you can look at to get ideas. Most network protocols are defined in RFC documents. Google "rfc <protocol-name>" to find these specifications.

Comment: Also, your application protocol will have to provide for the fact that the sender might want to send "self-contained messages", but the receiver will possibly be getting those piece by piece (TCP is a stream protocol, not message-based). And if you want to multiplex several logical connections over one physical TCP connection the protocol has to allow for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  This definitely gives me the direction I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP / TCP / IP is a worthy protocol stack, either for you to use as an example or simply to use directly.  It has a header that's perfect for what you have described: Content-Type. For example,

```
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

This declares that the data stream to follow is HTML coded in the Latin-1 character set.

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

This says the data stream is JPEG.

There's a lot of details here.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

C# (dotNet) has tons of fully debugged support for this.